# SilverLight: how to ensure ListBox completely frees its children UIElements

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox, silverlight-5.0, listboxitem

If I have a Model like this:

public class LayerViewModel
    {

```
    public LayerViewModel(string name, string alias, UIElement representation)
    {
        Name = name;
        Alias = alias;
        Representation = representation;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }

    public UIElement Representation
    {
        get; private set; 
    }                  
}
```

Using the following DataTemplate:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Representation, Mode=OneTime}"/>
                        <TextBlock 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Alias}" 
                                   FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"
                                   Margin="16 21 0 20" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>                            
                        </Grid>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

If you bind a collection of these models to a ListBox, navigate away and back to the ListBox's containing page, your application will crash.  This is because LayerViewModel.Representation is not released from the VisualTree even if the ListBox's ItemSource is set to null when its containing page is being unloaded. I used DependencyObject.GetVisualAncestors() to confirm this.

How do I get a ListBox to  completely frees all of the UIElements that comprsises of its VisualTree?  Setting its ItemsSource to null doesn't achieve this.

Comment: And you tried to change the mode of binding such as Mode=OneWay?

Comment: No did not try OneWay.  If OneTime doesn't release it then OneWay would not.

Comment: Change type of Representation to string. Try to create DataTemplate which will contain your Uielement. And enter it in ContentTemplate property of ContentControl. That is, your content will have to adapt to the data in the model, for example using a ValueConverter.

Comment: @bobah75, Representation cannot be a string since it could represent a relatively complex object graph.  However, I did end up doing things differently by exposing a different property and using a ValueConverter as you stated.  This sounds like a bug in ListBox though.